# finding mean by factor for range conditioned on group maximum

Tags: r, aggregate

This feels like it shouldn't be hard, and yet I've been fighting it without being able to find an answer that fits so I thought I would ask.

I have a dataset that I want to split by a factor column, then take a mean. That is easy. The complication is that I want to further restrict that mean to only the values within a certain range of the maximum of a second column.

As an example, using `mtcars`, I'd like the mean `hp`, `drat` & `wt` grouped by cylinders (`cyl`), and within 50cc's of the maximum displacement (`disp`).

Using `aggregate` the subset argument doesn't apply to each subset, it applies to the entire dataset. So, we get only the correct average for 8-cylinder cars, not for 4 or 6.

```
aggregate(data=mtcars, cbind(hp, drat, wt) ~ factor(cyl), FUN=mean, subset=c(disp<=max(disp) & disp>=max(disp)-50))

#factor(cyl)       hp     drat       wt
#1           8 216.6667 3.053333 5.339667
```

Using `by` yields a warning and an NA

```
by(data=mtcars, mtcars$cyl, function(x) mean(subset(x, disp<=max(disp) & disp>=max(disp)-50), select = hp:wt))

Warning messages:
1: In mean.default(subset(x, disp <= max(disp) & disp >= max(disp) -  :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

I'm clearly missing something here. What I'm looking for is to return a data frame  with rows for each cylinder (4, 6, 8) and columns with mean for hp, drat and wt for only the cars in the top 50cc's for each group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this does the trick using `dplyr`...

```
library(dplyr)
data <- mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% filter(max(disp)-disp<=50) %>%
            summarise_each(funs="mean",hp,drat,wt)

data
# A tibble: 3 × 4
    cyl        hp     drat       wt
  <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
1     4  91.16667 3.950000 2.674167
2     6 107.50000 2.920000 3.337500
3     8 216.66667 3.053333 5.339667
```

Comment: The RStudio dplyr and tidyr cheat sheet is a good starting point

Answer (score 3):

A base R method using the split-apply-combine methodology is

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(split(mtcars, mtcars$cyl), function(i) {
       sapply(i[i$disp<=max(i$disp) & i$disp>=max(i$disp)-50, c("hp", "drat", "wt")], mean)))
         hp     drat       wt
4  91.16667 3.950000 2.674167
6 107.50000 2.920000 3.337500
8 216.66667 3.053333 5.339667
```

Here, the data is split into a list of data.frames by cyl and then subset according to your criteria. Then the mean is calculated for the desired variables. The resulting list is rbinded into a data.frame using `do.call`.

Comment: Thanks! I upvoted this but picked Andrew's `dplyr` solution since it's so much more concise.

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness, here is also a `data.table` solution.

The OP has requested *to return a data frame with rows for each `cylinder` (4, 6, 8) and columns with mean for `hp`, `drat` and `wt` for only the cars in the top 50cc's for each group*. So there are two tasks:

1. Select cars which fulfill the condition
2. Aggregate relevant columns by group

With `data.table` this becomes

```
library(data.table)
mtcars <- as.data.table(mtcars)
mtcars[mtcars[, .I[disp >= max(disp) - 50], by = cyl]$V1, 
       lapply(.SD, mean), .SDcols = c("hp", "drat", "wt"), keyby = cyl]
```

> ```
>    cyl        hp     drat       wt
> 1:   4  91.16667 3.950000 2.674167
> 2:   6 107.50000 2.920000 3.337500
> 3:   8 216.66667 3.053333 5.339667
> ```

The first task is accomplished by

```
mtcars[, .I[disp >= max(disp) - 50], by = cyl]$V1
```

which returns the row numbers of the cars which fulfill the condition to be within the top 50cc's of each group.

Finally, the selected rows are aggregated by group as requested.

Note that `setDT(mtcars)` can not be used as usual because `mtcars` resides within a package that is locked to prevent modifying its variable bindings.